# Check for Duplicate values and Pull Info to New Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (*df_data*) with 14 columns for info over 1 month. I pulled out one week's data (*df1*) and made a list of all the account numbers there (*accounts1*)

What I am trying to do is take that *accounts1* list and have it go through each value in the list, checking if it is counted more than once in *df_data* and if so, to save that account number to a new list for repeats only.

Then I want to take that repeats list and pull the 14 columns out of the original *df_data* so I can have all the rows of all 14 columns for each occurrence of that account number.

I'm getting stuck with the list of repeated account numbers, I used the following code, which seems to have worked to create a list with results

```
cnt = collections.Counter(accounts1)
repeats.append([k for k, v in cnt.items() if v > 1])
print((repeats).count)
```

but the amount of elements in that list is right under 3,000. When I used the *.unique* and checked the difference it should be a little over 5,000. What am I doing wrong? And how can I then use those elements to pull the columns from the original dataframe?

Basically say I had

```
accounts1 = df1['accntnum'] = [0,1,2,5,8,2,5,0,0,7]
```

I would want it to cycle through and pull out each repeat from df_data and return a list of them like

```
repeats = [0, 2, 5, 7] 
(There are numbers in the monthly df_data that are in weekly df1 but may not be repeated there yet)
```

Then I'd like to use that list to pull from df_data['accntnum'], thinking something like

```
df_repeats = df_data[df_data['accntnum'] isin repeats]]
```

Oh also, I'm really only interested in the first occurrence of a repeat. There is a date and time column that can help sort those out in the end though. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `df_data[df_data['acctnum'].isin(repeats)].sort_values(['date', 'time']).drop_duplicates(keep='first')` ?

Comment: Didn't quite work since it only kept the initial occurrence and not the first repetition as well like I needed, but it helped put me on the right track, thank you!                         I ended up sorting my df_data, creating a new df_first using the drop_duplicates(keep = 'first') like you suggested for the initial occurrence of each account number. Then, I used drop() to get rid of those first occurrences from df_data and repeated process to get second occurrences in their own dataframe, then combined the 2.                         Thank you!